# SQL query: please help weird output on SQL query. (Counting each client latest status)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I used to ask this question in this SO and already got the solution, however, that sql query produced only partial correct result. I have tried to figure it out but it seem to complicate for me to understand. So would you please kindly help me. Thank you.

for table tbl_sActivity

```
   act_id| Client_id | act_status| user_id | act_date 
    1    |      7    |    warm   |     1   | 19/7/12 
    2    |      7    |    dealed |     1   | 30/7/12 <- lastest status of client(7)          
    3    |      8    |    hot    |     1   | 6/8/12  <- lastest status of client(8)
    4    |      5    |    cold   |    22   | 7/8/12  <- lastest status of client(5)
    5    |      6    |    cold   |     1   | 16/7/12
    6    |      6    |    warm   |     1   | 18/7/12
    7    |      6    |    dealed |     1   | 7/8/12  <- lastest status of client(6)   
    8    |      9    |    warm   |    26   | 2/8/12
    9    |     10    |    warm   |    26   | 2/8/12  
    10   |      9    |    hot    |    26   | 4/8/12  <- lastest status of client(9)
    11   |     10    |    hot    |    26   | 4/8/12
    12   |     10    |    dealed |    26   | 10/8/12 <- lastest status of client(10)
    13   |     13    |    dealed |    26   | 8/8/12  <- lastest status of client(13)
    14   |     11    |    hot    |    25   | 8/8/12
    15   |     11    |    dealed |    25   | 14/8/12 <- lastest status of client(11)
```

I want to produce the User Progressive Report that shows the latest progress of how each user follow up his/her clients. 
Therefore this report must show number of each user's clients group by each of their latest status.

The **correct** output should be looked like this..

```
user_id | act_status | Count(act_status)
1       |   dealed   |    2
1       |    hot     |    1
22      |    cold    |    1 
25      |   dealed   |    1
26      |    hot     |    1
26      |   dealed   |    2
```

The SQL query that I had is below:

```
select user_id, act_status, count(act_Status)
from your_table
where act_date in (
    select  max(act_date)
    from your_table
    group by Client_id
)
group by user_id, act_status
```

which when i add more transactions to the database, the output went **wrong** like this..

```
user_id | act_status | Count(act_status)
1       |   dealed   |    2
1       |    hot     |    1
22      |    cold    |    1
25      |    hot     |    1 ** (this one shouldn't show up)
25      |   dealed   |    1
26      |    hot     |    2 ** (should be only '1')
26      |   dealed   |    2
```

Comment: That was the answer you accepted in a previous question. Did you accept just because it seemed to run after you edited in a table name?

Comment: @Remou I accepted because it returned the correct result before I added more transactions of user (25) and (26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried and tested:

```
SELECT S.user_id, S.act_status, Count(S.act_status) AS CountOfact_status
FROM tbl_sActivity AS S INNER JOIN [SELECT A.client_id, Max(A.act_date) AS max_act
FROM tbl_sActivity AS A
GROUP BY A.client_id]. AS S2 ON (S.act_date = S2.max_act) AND (S.client_id = S2.client_id)
GROUP BY S.user_id, S.act_status
```

A similar request to an answer I gave yesterday, please try and read through my query as well as just using it, this will hopefully help you understand and is the only way to learn : )

Comment: don't know how to thank you enough!!.. really thank you.. ;) you're really kind.

Comment: @Alxan Your welcome, it's why were all here and why the site continues to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Will it not be better if you use the primary key column: act_id, instead of using the date column.

Thus, getting the max primary key?

What I meant was, instead of this:

```
where act_date in (
    select  max(act_date)
    from your_table
    group by Client_id
)
```

something like this:

```
  where act_id in (
select max(act_id)-- for each user, can't think of syntax now, but this could point you into the right direction
    )
```

BugFinder's answer looks better.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user_id, act_status, count(act_Status) 
from your_table left join 
(select act_date in ( 
    select  max(act_date) 
    from your_table 
    group by Client_id 
) as t where t.client_id = your_table.client_id and t.act_date = your_table.act_date
group by user_id, act_status
```

Should give you what you wanted

Eg make a table of max dates by client, then link it back to your table using both fields to be precise.

Comment: Or as ysterpoot says, use the act_id either way, you need to join on both as your query used date and user 26 had 2 hots on the same day.Hence it counted 2 not 1.

Comment: well..it said "syntax error in FROM Clause" (even though i replaced your_table with my real name table (tbl_sActivity).

Comment: Given its access then, you could make the qery of the select in the middle, and then select from that query rather than from the table itself. (If its going to be that picky)

Comment: If you had made the inner select a query, then the outer one selected using a join on the query, it would work. I just made one

Comment: sorry, I think your code will work well.. however with my very limited skill of SQL, I couldn't put it to good use.